# How to get Class from KClass for Dagger2 ViewModelFactory?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I am trying to convert [this code](https://github.com/techyourchance/dependency-injection-in-android-course/blob/viewmodel/app/src/main/java/com/techyourchance/journeytodependencyinjection/common/dependencyinjection/presentation/ViewModelModule.java) to `kotlin`

#### Dagger ViewModelModule.kt

```
@Module
class ViewModelModule {
    @Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    @MapKey
    internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)

    @Provides
    fun viewModelFactory(providerMap: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>): ViewModelFactory {
        return ViewModelFactory(providerMap)
    }

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(RepositioryListViewModel::class)
    fun questionDetailsViewModel(fetchRepoListUseCase: FetchRepoListUseCase): ViewModel {
        return RepositioryListViewModel(fetchRepoListUseCase)
    }
}
```

#### ViewModelFactory.kt

```
class ViewModelFactory(providerMap: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private val mProviderMap: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> = providerMap

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return mProviderMap[modelClass]!!.get() as T
    }

}
```

Dagger is not able to map my ViewModel Factory Argument's to the Provider map as it need's Class as the `key`

```
@Provides
    fun viewModelFactory(providerMap: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>): ViewModelFactory {
        return ViewModelFactory(providerMap)
    }
```

But,

The problem here is i can't do this

```
    @ViewModelKey(RepositioryListViewModel::javaClass)
    @ViewModelKey(RepositioryListViewModel::class.java)
```

As it Give's me below Compile time error

> An Annotation Argument must be compile-time constant

I have tried searching for many reference but haven't found anything helpful.

**How can i convert [this code](https://github.com/techyourchance/dependency-injection-in-android-course/blob/viewmodel/app/src/main/java/com/techyourchance/journeytodependencyinjection/common/dependencyinjection/presentation/ViewModelModule.java) to kotlin??**

Comment: See https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-dagger-2-multibindings-viewmodel-8418eb372848

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks it worked (Y)